# Any Freeware utility available to convert .pl file Into .exe for Windows7

Tags: perl

can anyone pls suggest how I can convert my Perl file Into an executable .exe file on windows 7. I tried Installing pp module but Installation failed may be because I was using Free version of Perl ?

I tried Perl2Exe as well by I am getting any output from the generated .exe file.

Comment: Free version of perl?

Comment: I think he refers to the Community Edition of ActivePerl from ActiveState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Community Edition of ActivePerl - that's only one of the available distributions of Perl for Windows. Another is StrawberryPerl, which bundles a lot more modules and a better (more usable) toolchain for compiling own modules.

You could try to install/use `pp` with that, but I doubt the success. As far as I know, one of the modules needed by PAR::Packer (and thus, `pp`) is broken for Perl versions > 5.18.

Another possibility would be Perl2Exe from IndigoStar. This practically bundles a perl interpreter and the needed modules with your script and gives you the .exe you wish for.

There are other projects like that out there, but I only tested a few...

Comment: No Success with Perl2Exe from Indigostar as well . It say some packages are missing though I have installed but still not able to open the generated .exe file . Any other way around ?